# How to delete to start of pattern on another line?

Tags: design-patterns, vim, line

I would like to know if it is possible to delete till the start of a pattern on another line.

p.e.

1. good morning |
2. empty line
3. empty line
4. empty line
5. ....
6. empty line
7. hello world

Is it possible to delete from cursor "|" in line 1 till "world in line 7?
(remaining in normal mode)

I do this often. Normally I use "dd" to delete all lines between line 1 and line 7 and then delete to word "dfw"
but this is quit difficult if I'm on line 347 and my text is on 381. I have to count the lines between them and often I delete one line too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using `dd` (which deletes a single line), you can use the more general `d` command as follows (^ is your cursor)

```
^The quick
 brown fox
 jumped over
 the lazy
 dog
```

Type `d/the` then press enter. It will delete from the cursor to the beginning of the first search match, leaving you with

```
 the lazy
 dog
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.  p.e. d/the does a search to "the"

Comment: It should search forward to the "the" and delete everything before it. It won't delete the "the" itself. You won't see anything but the search until you press enter.

Comment: found it. Searchcomplete plugin. I removed it and now it works fine.  Thank you for your answer. Thanks Felix Kling also.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for "world":

```
d/world<Enter>
```